# Proper way of implementing XSRF Protection in Java

Tags: java, angularjs, security, session, jakarta-ee

I am implementing XSRF protection in a j2ee application. When the user is logged on, I generate a TOKEN and add a session cookie:

```
response.addCookie(new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN",TOKEN));
Utilities util = new Utilities(TOKEN);
request.getSession().setAttribute("utils", util);
```

Apart from addting the `cookie` I save the TOKEN in a Utilities object and set the `util` object as a session attribute.
Then, for every `request` I check the `request.getHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN")` if it matches with the TOKEN I have saved in the `util` object.

Is this the proper way of implementing the XSRF protection? I'm not user I should save the TOKEN in the session or not. If this is not the best way of doing it, what are other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: in Spring Security you should add `http.csrf()` in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. This is very useful doc - [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html).

Comment: OK, but I'm not using Spring Security. I just want to know if I'm doing it wrong by saving the TOKEN in an object that is set as a session attribute?